# How to change the direction of a chain-sprocket system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, power-transmission, transmission, bicycles

I’m looking for a way to change the direction (90 °) of a motion transmitted by a basic chain-sprocket system. Is there such a thing as a chain-driven equivalent to straight bevel gears?

I’m planning on buying a piece of land and building an off-the-grid cabin and I have been investigating ways to power certain appliances without electricity and I have been inspired by a Guatemalan non-profit organization, Pedal Maya, that builds bike-powered (kinetic) appliances (so-called "bicimaquinas"); they use one bike per appliance, but I would like to be able to use only one bike for multiple appliances. The issue is that some appliances (e.g. food blender) are not parallel to the bike chain while some are (e.g. washing machine). My mechanic skills are quite basic, so a simple solution would be the best. Thanks!

PS: Here is a document that shows how the bicimaquina food processor is build (from Pedal Maya, in Spanish): https://ecotec.unam.mx/wp-content/uploads/BiciDesgranadoraMaiz.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Pulleys with rope or belts would work.

Sizing and slippage will need to be considered.

Comment: Round belts, square belts, and hex belts are all available. The hex belts run in standard sheaves. The square belts need special sheaves. This will all cost a lot more than buying and running a small generator.

Comment: @PhilSweet Op seems clear that the motive power is a bike, not a generator.